# How to get ClientPeoplePicker value using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

can anyone please tell me, How to get ClientPeoplePicker value using javascript.?

Comment: check this one: http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-clientpeoplepicker.html

Comment: or also check this one http://sharepointstack.blogspot.com/2013/05/get-and-set-user-in-client-people.html or another nice blog http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783581/Client-people-picker-on-a-custom-SharePoint-form

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE In http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783581/Client-people-picker-on-a-custom-SharePoint-form link, it is written that fd.field('User').control('ready', function() {
can you please tell me what is fd in above statement.?

Comment: I wrote a post a while ago how to create a client people picker and get the values: https://bmspblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/18/creating-a-people-picker-in-a-web-part-page-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just need to access the values, you could do it like this:

```
var dispTitle = "APickerField";      
var pickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + dispTitle + "']");      
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
```

The `GetAllUserInfo()` returns an array with one index pr entity in the picker, with the following properties available:

[image]

**Update**

This is the form field:
[image]

And this the tag you need to get the ID from:
[image]

```
APickerField_bec5d6be-a12e-4cfd-8046-558427c2687c_$ClientPeoplePicker
```

So one could just have done it like this:

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["APickerField_bec5d6be-a12e-4cfd-8046-558427c2687c_$ClientPeoplePicker"].GetAllUserInfo()
```

And if you check the SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict object, it will have all your pickers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i will try and let you know if it solves my problem

Comment: I am getting error ' Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference ' at peoplePicker line

Comment: That's probably because it didn't find any controller. "APickerField" is the Display Title to the field, so you'll have to change that to the field you use, or get the reference by another method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now its working. 

i have added client people picker programatically, so it was generating tag other way. then i updated my id to         
var dispTitle = "ASPD_Editors";
var pickerDiv = $("[id$='aspd_ctrl_ASPD_Editors_TopSpan'][title='" + dispTitle + "']");

And now finally its working. i almost wasted my 1 day on it.
Thank you very much Anders.

Comment: What if I want value of Department property?

Comment: @Ashish The department value should be in the EntityData object.

Comment: @User5590 or you can use the following: var pickerDiv = $("[id$='<%=ClientPeoplePickerObjectID.ClientID %>_TopSpan'][title='" + dispTitle + "']");

Answer (score 3):

```
<pre>/* get value from clientPeoplePicker */

// value from first input field in client people picker div
var data = $("Div[title='Antragssteller'] > input" ).val(); 
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

// and now you can see the properties
alert(jsonData[0].DisplayText);
</pre>
/*
    [
    {
    "Key":"i:0#.w|xyz\\xyz",
    "Description":"xyz\\xyz",
    "DisplayText":"Doe, John",
    "EntityType":"User",
    "ProviderDisplayName":"Active Directory",
    "ProviderName":"AD",
    "IsResolved":true,
    "EntityData":
        {"Title":"",
        "MobilePhone":"",
        "SIPAddress":"",
        "Department":"",
        "Email":"xyz@xyz"
        },
    "MultipleMatches":[],
    "AutoFillKey":"i:0#.w|xyz\\xyze",
    "AutoFillDisplayText":"Doe, John",
    "AutoFillSubDisplayText":"",
    "AutoFillTitleText":"xyz@xyz\nActive Directory\xyz\\xyz",
    "DomainText":"xyz.local",
    "Resolved":true,
    "LocalSearchTerm":"xcv"
    }
    ]

*/
```

Comment: this is awesome! where were you a year ago when I needed this? i did it the long way but this is way better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnValueChangedClientScript` property of `ClientPeoplePicker` as follows:

Markup:

`<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker ID="peoplePicker1" runat="server" ClientModeOnValueChangedClientScript="peoplePicker1_ValueChanged" />`

JavaScript:

`var selectedUsers = [];
function peoplePicker1_ValueChanged(elemId, userKeys) {
    if (elemId.indexOf('peoplePicker1') !== -1) {
        if (userKeys.length > 0) {
           for (var i = 0; i < userKeys.length; i++) {
                selectedUsers.push(userKeys[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            selectedUsers = [];
        }
    }
}`

Reference: [ClientPeoplePicker.OnValueChangedClientScript property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.onvaluechangedclientscript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the picker id for SharePoint Client People Picker change event. I have got the same using `OnUserResolvedClientScript` as below. Here to get the picker div I have followed the approach of getting it via the people picker text box `id` and the `title name` which you can get the by inspecting the element. put the below code in  `$(document).ready` function. Happy Coding

---

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function() {
var pickerDiv = $("[id^='Employee_x0020_Name'][title='Employee Name']");
var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
picker.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function(peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
 //It will get the desired display name of the people from picker div, similarly any other property can be accessed via selectedUsersInfo
    var empname = selectedUsersInfo[0].DisplayText;
    console.log(empname);
    }
});
```