# how to get people picker text using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to compare text of 2 people picker which are on same form.how to do it using JavaScript or Jquery. I have already gone through so many blogs but they are not providing the exact solution that i want.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109690/how-to-get-clientpeoplepicker-value-using-javascript/109707#109707

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Sharepoint function to do it that is called `GetPickerControlValue`. You'll need to known the HTML ID of the both fields. Then just use `GetPickerControlValue("ID_of_the_UserField", false, false)` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

[SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com) is free javascript library which does this very well.

[Example](http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=People%20fields)

You need to add the js reference in your master page.

```
// Get the field
var peopleField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Assigned To'); 
//here "assigned to" is field name
```

[spservices.js](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) also supports this.
[Example](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker)

```
var salesRep = $().SPFindPeoplePicker({
    peoplePickerDisplayName: "Column Display Name"    
});
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Devang. how i will get mail id of user.

Comment: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker

check the example there, he shows how to get email from People Picker