# People Picker in sharepoint 2010 in Client Object model

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-server, people-picker

I want to implement a people picker functionality in sharepoint 2010 with Client Object Model (JSOM), how to do it?

Actually i have implementated in 2013 but the same code does not work on 2010.

Comment: show what you already have then

Comment: check the : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/peoplepicker-using-jsom/134955#134955

Comment: Have you tried code for SP2013 which are available on Office PnP at Github?

Comment: No, provide it with the link...