# JSOM peoplepicker 500 error

Tags: visual-web-part, people-picker, jsom, csom

I am implementing a people picker on my visual webpart to allow users to query a list according to a person. My implementation is similar to the post found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/134955/31470), but when typing in the people picker I see the following:

[image]

In the browser console, we see there was a 500 error on the request.

[image]

I have double checked that I am including the necessary `.js` files and also have tried performing an `IISRESET` with no success.

I have very little experience working with `JSOM` so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *JSOM* in the past I have experienced this trouble when I have a lack of system resources, specifically when my **systems RAM has less than 5% available**.

The fact that you are getting a Service Activation Exception leads me to believe this may very well be the case, and can be verified in Windows event viewer.

Close some applications or disable some services on the Host machine. You can look at changing your web.config to update the 'minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService'. ([Link to MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731336(v=vs.90).aspx))

Caveat: The issue with the people picker is not because of your explicit use of *JSOM*, but SharePoint fires it off in conjunction with use of the people picker.