# CSOM Get name from people picker (SPF2013)

Tags: javascript, csom, people-picker, jsom

I developped a js feature with a field people picker. I'd like to know how can i get the entered value Inside?

I've tried this without success because it's undefined.:

```
console.log(SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["peopleEditor"].GetAllUserInfo());
```

Here is my field

And how i initialize it

```
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

// Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['Width'] = '280px';

// Render and initialize the picker. 
// Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
// PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
// picker properties.
this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
```

}

Comment: tried this - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109690/how-to-get-clientpeoplepicker-value-using-javascript  ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the people picker through JS tends to add "_TopSpan" to your container id. Try:

`SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["peopleEditor_TopSpan"].GetAllUserInfo()`

or, if you're only interested in display names

`SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["peopleEditor_TopSpan"].GetResolvedUsersAsText()`

If neither works, double check the people picker dictionary entries in case things went wonky in the generated name.

Comment: Hi, i tried this but it's undefined. i checked in developer Tools and i have something in: SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["peopleEditor_TopSpan"] but nothing in getAllUserInfo()

Comment: the G should be capitalized (my mistake).  edited the answer with correct casing